# lapply calculations across multiple lists

Tags: r

This question has two parts which are similar:

Question 1:

I have a list of 2 data frames for Alibaba, Alphabet. I am trying to make caluclations for all two firms within the list. So for example for all lists within the list take `Sales, General and administrative / Operating income`.

Where I am trying to get an output of specific ratios for each of the firms across the years (alternatively just for the year 2017-03).

`BS` Data:

```
BS <- structure(list(Alibaba = structure(list(V1 = c("Fiscal year ends in March. CNY in millions except per share data.", 
"Assets", "Current assets", "Cash", "Cash and cash equivalents", 
"Short-term investments", "Total cash", "Receivables", "Inventories", 
"Deferred income taxes", "Prepaid expenses", "Other current assets", 
"Total current assets", "Non-current assets", "Property, plant and equipment", 
"Land", "Fixtures and equipment", "Other properties", "Property and equipment, at cost", 
"Accumulated Depreciation", "Property, plant and equipment, net", 
"Equity and other investments", "Goodwill", "Intangible assets", 
"Deferred income taxes", "Other long-term assets", "Total non-current assets", 
"Total assets", "Liabilities and stockholders' equity", "Liabilities", 
"Current liabilities", "Short-term debt", "Accounts payable", 
"Taxes payable", "Accrued liabilities", "Deferred revenues", 
"Other current liabilities", "Total current liabilities", "Non-current liabilities", 
"Long-term debt", "Deferred taxes liabilities", "Accrued liabilities", 
"Deferred revenues", "Minority interest", "Other long-term liabilities", 
"Total non-current liabilities", "Total liabilities", "Stockholders' equity", 
"Common stock", "Other Equity", "Additional paid-in capital", 
"Retained earnings", "Treasury stock", "Accumulated other comprehensive income", 
"Total stockholders' equity", "Total liabilities and stockholders' equity"
), V2 = c("2018-03", "", "", "", "199309", "10901", "210210", 
"25370", "4535", "", "5760", "10980", "256855", "", "", "", "35909", 
"51019", "86928", "-20439", "66489", "177892", "162149", "36842", 
"2182", "14715", "460269", "717124", "", "", "", "6028", "", 
"16071", "66930", "22297", "24484", "135810", "", "119525", "19312", 
"", "993", "70616", "5046", "215492", "351302", "", "1", "3854", 
"186764", "172353", "-2233", "5083", "365822", "717124"), V3 = c("2017-03", 
"", "", "", "143736", "7065", "150801", "21374", "", "652", "4176", 
"5513", "182516", "", "", "", "19311", "13156", "32467", "-12261", 
"20206", "151820", "125420", "18799", "386", "7665", "324296", 
"506812", "", "", "", "14897", "", "7674", "36025", "15052", 
"20123", "93771", "", "76835", "10154", "", "641", "42330", "4282", 
"134242", "228013", "", "1", "3393", "164585", "108558", "-2823", 
"5085", "278799", "506812"), V4 = c("2016-03", "", "", "", "106818", 
"8878", "115696", "11738", "", "451", "3891", "2294", "134070", 
"", "", "", "13772", "8038", "21810", "-8181", "13629", "120853", 
"81645", "8246", "30", "5977", "230380", "364450", "", "", "", 
"4304", "1051", "3733", "15352", "10297", "17302", "52039", "", 
"53467", "6471", "", "418", "32552", "2516", "95424", "147463", 
"", "1", "2356", "132206", "78752", "", "3672", "216987", "364450"
), V5 = c("2015-03", "", "", "", "108193", "17806", "125999", 
"11163", "", "256", "815", "3876", "142109", "", "", "", "10259", 
"4646", "14905", "-5766", "9139", "48488", "41933", "9680", "157", 
"3928", "113325", "255434", "", "", "", "1990", "667", "3368", 
"7035", "7914", "18698", "39672", "", "50603", "4493", "", "445", 
"11974", "2808", "70323", "109995", "", "1", "1563", "117142", 
"24842", "", "1891", "145439", "255434"), V6 = c("2014-03", "", 
"", "", "33045", "12029", "45074", "16006", "", "191", "226", 
"6336", "67833", "", "", "", "5947", "3214", "9161", "-3580", 
"5581", "20689", "11793", "3566", "66", "2021", "43716", "111549", 
"", "", "", "10364", "3308", "1972", "7021", "6496", "8223", 
"37384", "", "30711", "2136", "18", "428", "1079", "10455", "44827", 
"82211", "", "1", "2474", "27043", "1183", "", "-1363", "29338", 
"111549"), V7 = c("2013-03", "", "", "", "30396", "2919", "33315", 
"4952", "", "208", "186", "4501", "43162", "", "", "", "3882", 
"2612", "6494", "-2686", "3808", "1797", "11294", "2229", "52", 
"1444", "20624", "63786", "", "", "", "5448", "2012", "1112", 
"5318", "4929", "5176", "23995", "", "22462", "643", "60", "389", 
"537", "15724", "39815", "63810", "", "1", "1337", "21655", "-20491", 
"", "-2526", "-24", "63786"), V8 = c("2012-03", "", "", "", "16857", 
"5480", "22337", "1315", "", "97", "139", "4011", "27899", "", 
"", "", "3114", "1565", "4679", "-2216", "2463", "1890", "11436", 
"2056", "43", "1423", "19311", "47210", "", "", "", "1283", "537", 
"745", "2484", "4350", "2352", "11751", "", "", "413", "", "529", 
"2895", "134", "3971", "15722", "", "1", "1096", "20778", "12552", 
"", "-2939", "31488", "47210"), V9 = c("2011-12", "", "", "", 
"3433", "8219", "11652", "559", "", "", "51", "978", "13241", 
"", "", "", "756", "594", "1350", "-617", "733", "235", "455", 
"224", "", "408", "2054", "15295", "", "", "", "1286", "16", 
"472", "362", "3969", "854", "6961", "", "", "240", "", "454", 
"102", "120", "917", "7878", "", "0", "", "", "", "", "7417", 
"7418", "15295"), V10 = c("2010-12", "", "", "", "3254", "6803", 
"10057", "94", "", "", "294", "596", "11040", "", "", "", "696", 
"540", "1236", "-455", "781", "64", "368", "232", "101", "119", 
"1665", "12705", "", "", "", "93", "16", "105", "", "", "6171", 
"6385", "", "", "131", "", "333", "50", "54", "567", "6952", 
"", "0", "", "", "", "", "5753", "5753", "12705"), V11 = c("2009-12", 
"", "", "", "2749", "4518", "7266", "38", "", "", "309", "529", 
"8143", "", "", "169", "568", "327", "1064", "-281", "783", "26", 
"203", "166", "73", "63", "1314", "9457", "", "", "", "", "24", 
"35", "", "", "4038", "4097", "", "", "70", "", "204", "41", 
"68", "383", "4480", "", "0", "", "", "", "", "4977", "4977", 
"9457")), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", 
"V8", "V9", "V10", "V11"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-56L)), Alphabet = structure(list(V1 = c("Fiscal year ends in December. USD in millions except per share data.", 
"Assets", "Current assets", "Cash", "Cash and cash equivalents", 
"Short-term investments", "Total cash", "Receivables", "Inventories", 
"Deferred income taxes", "Prepaid expenses", "Other current assets", 
"Total current assets", "Non-current assets", "Property, plant and equipment", 
"Gross property, plant and equipment", "Accumulated Depreciation", 
"Net property, plant and equipment", "Equity and other investments", 
"Goodwill", "Intangible assets", "Deferred income taxes", "Other long-term assets", 
"Total non-current assets", "Total assets", "Liabilities and stockholders' equity", 
"Liabilities", "Current liabilities", "Short-term debt", "Capital leases", 
"Accounts payable", "Taxes payable", "Accrued liabilities", "Deferred revenues", 
"Other current liabilities", "Total current liabilities", "Non-current liabilities", 
"Long-term debt", "Capital leases", "Deferred taxes liabilities", 
"Deferred revenues", "Other long-term liabilities", "Total non-current liabilities", 
"Total liabilities", "Stockholders' equity", "Common stock", 
"Additional paid-in capital", "Retained earnings", "Accumulated other comprehensive income", 
"Total stockholders' equity", "Total liabilities and stockholders' equity"
), V2 = c("2017-12", "", "", "", "10715", "91156", "101871", 
"18336", "749", "", "", "3352", "124308", "", "", "59647", "-17264", 
"42383", "7813", "16747", "2692", "680", "2672", "72987", "197295", 
"", "", "", "", "", "3137", "881", "5464", "1432", "13269", "24183", 
"", "3943", "26", "430", "340", "15871", "20610", "44793", "", 
"40247", "", "113247", "-992", "152502", "197295"), V3 = c("2016-12", 
"", "", "", "12918", "73415", "86333", "14137", "268", "", "4575", 
"95", "105408", "", "", "47527", "-13293", "34234", "5878", "16468", 
"3307", "383", "1819", "62089", "167497", "", "", "", "", "", 
"2041", "554", "4198", "1099", "8864", "16756", "", "3935", "", 
"226", "202", "7342", "11705", "28461", "", "36307", "", "105131", 
"-2402", "139036", "167497"), V4 = c("2015-12", "", "", "", "16549", 
"56517", "73066", "11556", "", "", "3139", "2353", "90114", "", 
"", "40146", "-11130", "29016", "5183", "15869", "3847", "251", 
"3181", "57347", "147461", "", "", "", "3000", "225", "1931", 
"302", "7097", "788", "5967", "19310", "", "1995", "", "189", 
"151", "5485", "7820", "27130", "", "32982", "", "89223", "-1874", 
"120331", "147461"), V5 = c("2014-12", "", "", "", "18347", "46048", 
"64395", "9383", "", "1322", "3412", "2173", "80685", "", "", 
"32746", "-8863", "23883", "3079", "15599", "4607", "", "3280", 
"50448", "131133", "", "", "", "1999", "10", "1715", "96", "6386", 
"752", "5847", "16805", "", "2992", "236", "1971", "104", "4525", 
"9828", "26633", "", "28767", "", "75706", "27", "104500", "131133"
), V6 = c("2013-12", "", "", "", "18898", "39819", "58717", "8882", 
"426", "1526", "2827", "508", "72886", "", "", "23837", "-7313", 
"16524", "1976", "11492", "6066", "", "1976", "38034", "110920", 
"", "", "", "3000", "9", "2453", "24", "5484", "1062", "3876", 
"15908", "", "1990", "246", "1947", "139", "3381", "7703", "23611", 
"", "25922", "", "61262", "125", "87309", "110920"), V7 = c("2012-12", 
"", "", "", "14778", "33310", "48088", "7885", "505", "1144", 
"2132", "700", "60454", "", "", "17697", "-5843", "11854", "1469", 
"10537", "7473", "", "2011", "33344", "93798", "", "", "", "2549", 
"", "2012", "240", "4729", "895", "3912", "14337", "", "2988", 
"", "1872", "100", "2786", "7746", "22083", "", "22835", "", 
"48342", "538", "71715", "93798"), V8 = c("2011-12", "", "", 
"", "9983", "34643", "44626", "5427", "", "215", "1745", "745", 
"52758", "", "", "14400", "-4797", "9603", "790", "7346", "1578", 
"", "499", "19816", "72574", "", "", "", "1218", "", "588", "197", 
"2538", "547", "3825", "8913", "", "2986", "", "287", "44", "2199", 
"5516", "14429", "", "20264", "", "37605", "276", "58145", "72574"
), V9 = c("2010-12", "", "", "", "13630", "21345", "34975", "4252", 
"", "259", "1326", "750", "41562", "", "", "11771", "-4012", 
"7759", "523", "6256", "1044", "265", "442", "16289", "57851", 
"", "", "", "3465", "", "483", "37", "3256", "394", "2361", "9996", 
"", "", "", "", "35", "1579", "1614", "11610", "", "18235", "", 
"27868", "138", "46241", "57851"), V10 = c("2009-12", "", "", 
"", "10198", "14287", "24485", "3178", "", "644", "836", "23", 
"29167", "", "", "8130", "-3286", "4845", "129", "4903", "775", 
"263", "416", "11330", "40497", "", "", "", "", "", "216", "", 
"1264", "285", "982", "2747", "", "", "", "", "42", "1703", "1745", 
"4493", "", "0", "15817", "20082", "105", "36004", "40497"), 
    V11 = c("2008-12", "", "", "", "8657", "7189", "15846", "2642", 
    "", "286", "1404", "", "20178", "", "", "7576", "-2342", 
    "5234", "85", "4840", "997", "", "434", "11589", "31768", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "178", "82", "1013", "218", "812", "2302", 
    "", "", "", "13", "30", "1184", "1227", "3529", "", "0", 
    "14450", "13562", "227", "28239", "31768")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-51L))), .Names = c("Alibaba", "Alphabet"))
```

Question 2:

The second question is similar but making calculations across lists, so for example taking `Depreciation & amortization` from the `IS` list divided by `Revenue` from the `BS` list.

`IS` Data 2:

```
IS <- structure(list(Alibaba = structure(list(V1 = c("Cash Flows From Operating Activities", 
"Depreciation & amortization", "Amortization of debt discount/premium and issuance costs", 
"Investment/asset impairment charges", "Investments losses (gains)", 
"Deferred income taxes", "Stock based compensation", "Prepaid expenses", 
"Accounts payable", "Accrued liabilities", "Income taxes payable", 
"Other working capital", "Other non-cash items", "Net cash provided by operating activities", 
"Cash Flows From Investing Activities", "Investments in property, plant, and equipment", 
"Property, plant, and equipment reductions", "Acquisitions, net", 
"Purchases of investments", "Sales/Maturities of investments", 
"Purchases of intangibles", "Other investing charges", "Net cash used for investing activities", 
"Cash Flows From Financing Activities", "Short-term borrowing", 
"Long-term debt issued", "Long-term debt repayment", "Excess tax benefit from stock based compensation", 
"Common stock issued", "Preferred stock issued", "Redemption of preferred stock", 
"Repurchases of treasury stock", "Cash dividends paid", "Other financing activities", 
"Net cash provided by (used for) financing activities", "Effect of exchange rate changes", 
"Net change in cash", "Cash at beginning of period", "Cash at end of period", 
"Free Cash Flow", "Operating cash flow", "Capital expenditure", 
"Free cash flow", "Supplemental schedule of cash flow data"), 
    TTM = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "135415", 
    "135415", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "-141637", "-141637", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "33534", "33534", 
    "-2192", "25120", "148355", "173475", "", "135415", "", "105579", 
    ""), `2018-03` = c("", "22020", "264", "3111", "", "976", 
    "20075", "-14765", "23158", "", "6610", "7079", "56643", 
    "125171", "", "-25809", "", "-547", "-12602", "7223", "-4027", 
    "-48128", "-83890", "", "-4199", "46996", "-9452", "", "399", 
    "", "", "", "", "-13385", "20359", "-6067", "55573", "143736", 
    "199309", "", "125171", "-29836", "95335", ""), `2017-03` = c("", 
    "14292", "264", "3155", "", "281", "15995", "-8237", "5312", 
    "", "4698", "5486", "39080", "80326", "", "-12220", "", "-33204", 
    "2321", "4354", "-5326", "-34289", "-78364", "", "1127", 
    "28381", "-175", "1369", "14694", "", "", "-13182", "", "700", 
    "32914", "2042", "36918", "106818", "143736", "", "80326", 
    "-17546", "62780", ""), `2016-03` = c("", "6701", "264", 
    "2319", "", "1226", "16082", "-4012", "", "", "1237", "10567", 
    "22452", "56836", "", "-5438", "", "3395", "-52988", "16826", 
    "-5407", "781", "-42831", "", "1859", "765", "-146", "1120", 
    "693", "", "", "-19795", "", "-342", "-15846", "466", "-1375", 
    "108193", "106818", "", "56836", "-10845", "45991", ""), 
    `2015-03` = c("", "4415", "166", "175", "", "1659", "13028", 
    "-2253", "", "", "1410", "2697", "19920", "41217", "", "-4770", 
    "", "-11526", "-36360", "1038", "-2935", "1099", "-53454", 
    "", "1070", "156781", "-131807", "", "61831", "", "", "-270", 
    "-104", "-4", "87497", "-112", "75148", "33045", "108193", 
    "", "41217", "-7705", "33512", ""), `2014-03` = c("", "1654", 
    "", "44", "-90", "1466", "2844", "-3567", "", "3992", "1008", 
    "-5926", "24954", "26379", "", "-3285", "", "-778", "-27891", 
    "461", "-1491", "-13", "-32997", "", "258", "83348", "-70817", 
    "", "2080", "", "-5131", "-157", "-208", "-9", "9364", "-97", 
    "2649", "30396", "33045", "", "26379", "-4776", "21603", 
    ""), `2013-03` = c("", "935", "", "175", "", "104", "1259", 
    "-354", "", "", "-116", "3606", "8867", "14476", "", "-1046", 
    "301", "499", "-512", "2770", "-1457", "-10", "545", "", 
    "-145", "33684", "-6607", "", "16792", "10542", "", "-40111", 
    "-103", "-15458", "-1406", "-76", "13539", "16857", "30396", 
    "", "14476", "-2503", "11973", ""), `2012-03` = c("", "870", 
    "", "135", "138", "150", "1254", "-240", "", "1332", "230", 
    "466", "4940", "9275", "", "-749", "1", "-211", "-1269", 
    "5935", "-1419", "-2413", "-125", "", "121", "229", "-229", 
    "", "618", "", "", "-421", "", "157", "475", "-54", "9571", 
    "7286", "16857", "", "9275", "-2168", "7107", ""), `2011-12` = c("", 
    "253", "1", "3", "-6", "", "336", "-161", "0", "", "", "168", 
    "1587", "2182", "", "-160", "3", "9", "-9529", "7937", "-12", 
    "167", "-1585", "", "", "1426", "-279", "", "55", "", "", 
    "-418", "-948", "-81", "-244", "-5", "347", "3086", "3433", 
    "", "2182", "-172", "2010", ""), `2010-12` = c("", "227", 
    "", "", "", "", "341", "", "", "", "", "1031", "-1599", "", 
    "", "-288", "1", "-276", "-8114", "5805", "-6", "131", "-2747", 
    "", "94", "", "", "", "10", "", "", "-53", "", "", "51", 
    "-6", "-2702", "2749", "47", "", "", "-294", "", ""), `2009-12` = c("", 
    "127", "", "", "", "", "238", "", "", "", "", "926", "950", 
    "2240", "", "-411", "3", "-415", "-1426", "850", "-411", 
    "587", "-1222", "", "", "", "", "", "0", "", "", "-70", "-888", 
    "", "-958", "-0", "60", "2689", "2749", "", "2240", "-411", 
    "1829", "")), .Names = c("V1", "TTM", "2018-03", "2017-03", 
"2016-03", "2015-03", "2014-03", "2013-03", "2012-03", "2011-12", 
"2010-12", "2009-12"), row.names = 2:45, class = "data.frame"), 
    Alphabet = structure(list(V1 = c("Cash Flows From Operating Activities", 
    "Net income", "Depreciation & amortization", "Investment/asset impairment charges", 
    "Investments losses (gains)", "Deferred income taxes", "Stock based compensation", 
    "Change in working capital", "Accounts receivable", "Inventory", 
    "Prepaid expenses", "Accounts payable", "Accrued liabilities", 
    "Income taxes payable", "Other working capital", "Other non-cash items", 
    "Net cash provided by operating activities", "Cash Flows From Investing Activities", 
    "Investments in property, plant, and equipment", "Property, plant, and equipment reductions", 
    "Acquisitions, net", "Purchases of investments", "Sales/Maturities of investments", 
    "Purchases of intangibles", "Other investing activities", 
    "Net cash used for investing activities", "Cash Flows From Financing Activities", 
    "Debt issued", "Debt repayment", "Common stock issued", "Common stock repurchased", 
    "Excess tax benefit from stock based compensation", "Other financing activities", 
    "Net cash provided by (used for) financing activities", "Effect of exchange rate changes", 
    "Net change in cash", "Cash at beginning of period", "Cash at end of period", 
    "Free Cash Flow", "Operating cash flow", "Capital expenditure", 
    "Free cash flow"), TTM = c("", "16308", "7887", "", "-3888", 
    "-437", "8537", "13586", "-2811", "", "", "589", "8450", 
    "", "7358", "-79", "41914", "", "-20621", "94", "", "-77343", 
    "66850", "-1578", "", "-32598", "", "10527", "-10588", "320", 
    "-6326", "", "-4772", "-10839", "-40", "-1563", "15711", 
    "14148", "", "41914", "-22199", "19715"), `2017-12` = c("", 
    "12662", "6915", "", "194", "258", "7679", "9246", "-3768", 
    "", "", "731", "5846", "", "6437", "137", "37091", "", "-13184", 
    "99", "", "-93940", "74492", "-287", "1419", "-31401", "", 
    "4291", "-4377", "800", "-4846", "", "-4166", "-8298", "405", 
    "-2203", "12918", "10715", "", "37091", "-13471", "23620"
    ), `2016-12` = c("", "19478", "6144", "", "275", "-38", "6703", 
    "3300", "-2578", "", "312", "110", "2108", "", "3348", "174", 
    "36036", "", "-10212", "240", "", "-85618", "67839", "-986", 
    "-2428", "-31165", "", "8729", "-10064", "", "-3693", "", 
    "-3304", "-8332", "-170", "-3631", "16549", "12918", "", 
    "36036", "-11198", "24838"), `2015-12` = c("", "16348", "5063", 
    "", "334", "-179", "5203", "-409", "-2094", "", "-318", "203", 
    "1936", "", "-136", "-336", "26024", "", "-9915", "", "", 
    "-76540", "63330", "-236", "-350", "-23711", "", "13705", 
    "-13728", "", "-1780", "548", "-2422", "-3677", "-434", "-1798", 
    "18347", "16549", "", "26024", "-10151", "15873"), `2014-12` = c("", 
    "14444", "4979", "", "-285", "-104", "4279", "364", "-1641", 
    "", "459", "436", "1002", "", "108", "-1301", "22376", "", 
    "-10959", "", "386", "-58312", "51315", "-4888", "1403", 
    "-21055", "", "11625", "-11643", "", "", "648", "-2069", 
    "-1439", "-433", "-551", "18898", "18347", "", "22376", "-15847", 
    "6529"), `2013-12` = c("", "12920", "3939", "", "", "-437", 
    "3343", "-31", "-1307", "-234", "-696", "605", "967", "", 
    "634", "-1075", "18659", "", "-7358", "", "2525", "-46013", 
    "38914", "-1448", "-299", "-13679", "", "10768", "-11325", 
    "", "", "481", "-781", "-857", "-3", "4120", "14778", "18898", 
    "", "18659", "-8806", "9853"), `2012-12` = c("", "10737", 
    "2962", "", "", "-266", "2692", "898", "-787", "301", "-833", 
    "-499", "1061", "", "1655", "-404", "16619", "", "-3273", 
    "", "", "-34106", "35225", "-10568", "-334", "-13056", "", 
    "16109", "-14781", "", "", "188", "-287", "1229", "3", "4795", 
    "9983", "14778", "", "16619", "-13841", "2778"), `2011-12` = c("", 
    "9737", "1851", "110", "", "343", "1974", "630", "-1156", 
    "", "-262", "101", "1054", "", "893", "-80", "14565", "", 
    "-3438", "", "-1900", "-62095", "48746", "", "-354", "-19041", 
    "", "10905", "-10179", "", "", "86", "-5", "807", "22", "-3647", 
    "13630", "9983", "", "14565", "-3438", "11127"), `2010-12` = c("", 
    "", "1396", "", "", "9", "1376", "-99", "-1129", "", "-414", 
    "272", "959", "102", "111", "8399", "11081", "", "-4018", 
    "", "-1067", "-45055", "37099", "", "2361", "-10680", "", 
    "5246", "-1783", "", "-801", "94", "294", "3050", "-19", 
    "3432", "10198", "13630", "", "11081", "-4018", "7063"), 
        `2009-12` = c("", "6520", "1524", "", "", "-268", "1164", 
        "486", "-504", "", "262", "34", "401", "217", "76", "-111", 
        "9316", "", "-810", "", "-108", "-29204", "22103", "", 
        "", "-8019", "", "", "", "", "", "90", "143", "233", 
        "11", "1541", "8657", "10198", "", "9316", "-810", "8506"
        ), `2008-12` = c("", "4227", "1500", "1095", "", "-225", 
        "1120", "327", "-334", "", "-147", "-212", "353", "", 
        "667", "-191", "7853", "", "-2358", "", "-3320", "-15403", 
        "15763", "", "", "-5319", "", "", "", "", "", "159", 
        "-72", "88", "-46", "2575", "6082", "8657", "", "7853", 
        "-2358", "5494")), .Names = c("V1", "TTM", "2017-12", 
    "2016-12", "2015-12", "2014-12", "2013-12", "2012-12", "2011-12", 
    "2010-12", "2009-12", "2008-12"), row.names = 2:43, class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("Alibaba", 
"Alphabet"))
```

I can post what I have so far but its not getting me anywhere.

Comment: Please create smaller data examples which represent your situation.

Comment: May I ask what you mean by smaller data samples? each of the lists contains two firms. Do you suggest that I remove some of the variables for each firm to 2-3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the lapply on list-names trick here.
Instead of feeding the list itself to lapply you can feed the names vector and call a desired function. 
Within your function you first select the needed data from both your list (BS and IS) and after that you can work with it. 
For this to work the names from list BS and IS have to be the same. If this is not the case selecting data within your function will fail (or at least not deliver matching data-pairs).
I think it would also help to clean up the data in list BS a little if possible. Right now colnames and rownames are stored in row 1 and col 1. That makes working with the data a bit harder.

```
    your_function = function(name)
    {
     data <- BS[[name]] # load data from list BS
     data2 <- IS[[name]] # load data from list IS

     # the following calculations make no sence. Just for illustration
     temp <- data[5, 2:NCOL(data)] # select desired variable-row
     temp <- matrix(as.numeric(temp), ncol = NCOL(temp)) # convert selection into numeric format
     temp2 <- data[6, 2:NCOL(data)] # select desired variable-row number 2
     temp2 <- matrix(as.numeric(temp2), ncol = NCOL(temp2)) # convert it into numeric as well
     temp <- temp/temp2 # perform desired operation with variable 1 and 2 
     rownames(temp) <- paste0(data[5,1], " / ", data[6,1]) # set rownames

     # insert more calculations here by selecting more desired rows
     temp3 <- matrix(as.numeric(data2[7, 3:NCOL(data2)]), ncol = NCOL(data2)-2) # lets just take row 7 from data2
     temp3 <- temp/temp3 # lets divide temp by the value from data2
     rownames(temp3) <- paste0("values from BS / ", data2[7,1])

     # add all calculated rows together
     temp <- rbind(temp, temp3)
     colnames(temp) <- data[1,2:NCOL(data)] # set colnames
     print(names(data))
     return(temp) # return the results 
    }

    test <- lapply(names(BS), your_function)
    names(test) = names(BS)
    test
```

But have a look at your variable-rows again. It looks like a few of them appear 2 times but containing different values.

```
head(sort(table(BS$Alibaba$V1), decreasing = T))
# Accrued liabilities                  Deferred income taxes 
# 2                                      2 
# Deferred revenues                       Accounts payable 
# 2                                      1 
# Accumulated Depreciation Accumulated other comprehensive income 
# 1                                      1
```

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate this. I see your point about cleaning the data a little more. I have just ran it on the whole list and some of the calculations are not correct since the lists are different sizes. I will make sure all lists are identical and this should work perfectly. Thanks again!